# Why does Python if/else statement only return else condition when trying to reclassify field using ArcMap field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, python-parser, if-else

Using ArcGIS 10.4. I'm trying to reclassify values from a field (ECOREGION_DIVISION), which is in string format, into new values using the following Python syntax:

```
def Reclass(ECOREGION_DIVISION):
  if (ECOREGION_DIVISION == "Desert"):
    return "Not forest"
  else:
    return "Forest"
 
    Reclass(!ECOREGION_DIVISION!)
```

The result is that all the values in the `new_class` field are returned as `"Forest"` (the if statement does not return `"Not forest"` when value = `"Desert"`). The `new_class` field is also string format. Does this syntax seem correct?
[image]

Comment: Why are you passing `Code_new` to the `Reclass` function? You should be passing `Code1`. Furthermore, what type is `Code1`? If it happens to be text the `if` statement will always return 2.

Comment: Hi Marcelo: I've revised the syntax for a more realistic version of the code I'm trying to construct. The initial field is in string format and I want to rename certain records for a simpler classification field. I've switched out the input argument for the field I want to reclass and I still get a similar result.

Comment: Your syntax seems fine. Do the values happen to have a whitespace at the end?

Comment: `if (ECOREGION_DIVISION.strip() == "Desert"):`

Comment: That does not appear to be the issue, there are no spaces from what I can tell, and the .strip() function doens't work. I think that there may be something wrong with the field calculator since built in functions like .replace() don't work. I've read that I may need to reinstall arcgis and delete the registry and c folders?

Comment: What do you mean when you say these functions don't work? Do you get an error or you simply don't get the expected output?

Comment: Another shot, what happens if you say “DESERT” in ECOREGION_DIVISION.upper()?

Comment: I am able to get the function to operate now using a code class as the input argument. Not sure if this was the reason or I actually set up my output fields correctly this time. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I ended up creating a field of the class codes rather than the Ecoregion text as the input (as either a string or integer to test out). I made sure to create syntax according to the new fields (string vs integer). The Reclass function now classifies as either a text or number field (important to use quotes for the string).

Here is the python syntax for string reclass:

```
def Reclass(new_class):
  if new_class == "240":
    return "Marine"
  else:
    return "Not Marine"

Reclass( !new_class!)
```

[image]

And this is the syntax for a number reclass:

```
def Reclass(new_code):
  if new_code == 240:
    return 1
  else:
    return 2

Reclass( !new_code!)
```

[image]

I'm not exactly sure if the reason this works now is because I am using the class code field rather than the class field itself, or due to some other tweaking such as setting up correct field types.